# Using JButton in one class to change card in another class (using CardLayout)

Tags: java, swing, architecture, actionlistener

I build a GUI in which I nested several `JPanel` components into each other using different classes extending panel. In my `Menue` I have a `CenterPanel` and a `ButtonPanel`. The `ButtonPanel` contains buttons which implemented `ActionListener` interfaces. The `CenterPanel` uses `CardLayout` and I want to use said buttons to change the cards in the `CenterPanel`. The problem is, the buttons don't know anything about the `CenterPanel` or the cards in that panel.

I wanted to avoid putting all in just one class for the menue, but I don't know How to solve this without just writing everyting in one class?

Here is some of my code:

### `MenuePanel`

```
public class MenuePanel extends JPanel{

JButton startButton;
JButton exitButton;
JButton anleitungButton;
ButtonPanel buttonPanel;
TitlePanel titlePanel;
JPanel centerPanel;
CardLayout cardLayout;
TextPanel anleitungPanel;
TextPanel gameOverPanel;
TextPanel gameWonPanel;
TextPanel nextLevelPanel;
StartPanel startPanel;

public MenuePanel() {
    super();
    cardLayout = new CardLayout();
    setBackground(Color.CYAN);
    setBounds(0,0,800,600);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    titlePanel = new TitlePanel();
    add(titlePanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

    startPanel = new StartPanel();
    gameOverPanel = new TextPanel("Game Over!");
    gameWonPanel = new TextPanel("Game Won!");
    anleitungPanel = new TextPanel();
    nextLevelPanel = new TextPanel("Next Level!");
    centerPanel = new JPanel();

    centerPanel.setLayout(cardLayout);
    add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    centerPanel.add(startPanel, "1");
    centerPanel.add(gameOverPanel, "2");
    centerPanel.add(gameWonPanel, "3");
    centerPanel.add(anleitungPanel, "4");
    centerPanel.add(nextLevelPanel, "5");
    cardLayout.show(centerPanel, "2");

    buttonPanel = new ButtonPanel();
    add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    setVisible(true);
}
```

### `ButtonPanel`

```
public class ButtonPanel extends JPanel{

JButton startButton;
JButton exitButton;
JButton anleitungButton;

public ButtonPanel() {
    super();
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 100));
    setBackground(Color.CYAN);

    startButton = new JButton("start)");
    startButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,50));
    add(startButton);
    anleitungButton = new JButton("anleitung");
    anleitungButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,50));
    add(anleitungButton);
    exitButton = new JButton("exit");
    exitButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150,50));
    add(exitButton);

    CloseListener closeListener = new CloseListener();
    StartListener startListener = new StartListener();
    AnleitungListener anleitungListener = new AnleitungListener();
    startButton.addActionListener(startListener);
    anleitungButton.addActionListener(anleitungListener);
    exitButton.addActionListener(closeListener);

}
```

### `TextPanel`

```
public class TextPanel extends JPanel{
JLabel text;

public TextPanel(String panel) {
    super();
    text = new JLabel(panel, SwingConstants.CENTER);
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 400));
    text.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.ITALIC, 75));
    add(text);
}
```

### `AnleitungListener`

```
public class AnleitungListener implements ActionListener{

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

}
```

Am I doing this whole thing wrong and need to change the whole architecture? And if, how? Most examples on how to use ActionListeners are either just written in one class or way to complex for me to understand.

Comment: *"using different classes extending JPanels"* Don't extend classes without good reason.

Comment: @AndrewThompson thanks for editing, I will do it better next time. And I thought it would be a good idea to spread the code and not just put it into one big class. That's why I made several classes which act as special panels. I have no idea if this is good practice or bad practice or any practice at all since this is my first project ever...

Comment: *"And I thought it would be a good idea to spread the code and not just put it into one big class."* Sure, but it's not necessary to extend panel, just to have it coming from a separate class. For example, the separate class might have a method that creates a standard panel (adds components to it & otherwise configures it) and then returns it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a class in between to orchestrate the whole switching, to prevent sharing lots of instances between classes. I have created an example using a CardSwitcher that does exactly that.

Let me know if you found it useful.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Test extends JPanel {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");

        Test tst = new Test();
        frame.getContentPane().add(tst);

        frame.setSize(600, 600);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    public Test() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout();

        JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel(cardLayout);

        JPanel panelA = new JPanel();
        panelA.add(new JLabel("Panel A"));
        centerPanel.add(panelA, "A");
        JPanel panelB = new JPanel();
        panelB.add(new JLabel("Panel B"));
        centerPanel.add(panelB, "B");
        JPanel panelC = new JPanel();
        panelC.add(new JLabel("Panel C"));
        centerPanel.add(panelC, "C");

        CardSwitcher switcher = new CardSwitcher(centerPanel, cardLayout);
        ButtonPanel buttons = new ButtonPanel(switcher);

        add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(buttons, BorderLayout.SOUTH);


    }

    class ButtonPanel extends JPanel {
        public ButtonPanel(CardSwitcher switcher) {
            setLayout(new FlowLayout());

            JButton buttonA = new JButton("Show A");
            buttonA.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    switcher.switchTo("A");
                }
            });
            add(buttonA);

            JButton buttonB = new JButton("Show B");
            buttonB.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    switcher.switchTo("B");
                }
            });
            add(buttonB);

            JButton buttonC = new JButton("Show C");
            buttonC.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    switcher.switchTo("C");
                }
            });
            add(buttonC);

        }
    }


    class CardSwitcher {
        CardLayout layout;
        Container container;

        public CardSwitcher(Container container, CardLayout layout) {
            this.layout = layout;
            this.container = container;
        }

        public void switchTo(String card) {
            layout.show(container, card);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, needed some time to figure out how and why this works. Tried it and it works. Now I still have the problem that I have two nested CardLayouts and the buttons are in the inner one. I guess I have to pass the outer container so I can change the outer cards and if I want to change the inner ones, iterate through the content of the outer container till I find the panel I want to change :/

Comment: Basically, the CardSwitcher encapsulates the components and the "complexity" of switching. It prevents you from passing around lots of references to other components. You could create two instances of it, or adapt the class to accommodate two CardLayouts.